# Requirement of second pass for the Boyer-Moore Majority Vote Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, boyer-moore

I am studying the Boyer-Moore Algorithm (from [here](https://gregable.com/2013/10/majority-vote-algorithm-find-majority.html)) and I had a quick question - what is the need of the second pass (which essentially just 'confirms' by finding the frequency of that element).  Doesn't the first pass itself *guarantee* that the element found is the majority one?  I considered a few examples and *felt* that a single pass is enough.  Could you kindly provide some examples to counter my feeling?

The code (if required) is as below:

```
int majorityElement(vector<int>& nums) {
    int candidate=0, count=0;

    for(auto value: nums) {
        //update the candidate if the count == 0
        if(count==0)
            candidate=value;

        //if the value == candidate then increment count
        if(value==candidate)
            count++;
        else
        //decrement count
            count--;
    }

    //return candidate
    return candidate;
}
```

**Edit:**  If I understand correctly, the algorithm is only applicable when the frequency of the majority element is indeed greater than `(vector size())/2`.  So, is the second pass really required?  Whenever we code, we do some trivial sanity checks (like checking if the input vector is empty), so in this case, why do we have a 'sanity check' as a part of an algorithm?  Or is there something more to it?

Comment: You do understand that second pass can reject a possible candidate, right? So, If you won't make the second pass, How will it identify the false candidates?

Comment: I think you are taking it for granted that the list will always have a majority element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following intuition for the Boyer-Moore algorithm might shed some light on why two passes are necessary.

The algorithm is based on the following idea. Imagine each element of your array is a person in a room holding a card with a number on it. Each person in the room wanders around until they meet someone else. If the two people are holding different numbers, they each sit down. Otherwise, they keep moving around until they encounter someone else. Eventually, some number of people will be left standing.

If there is a true majority element, the group of the last people standing will definitely have the majority element because no matter how people pair off there’s too many people in the majority for all of them to have been eliminated. But if there isn’t a majority, there could still be someone left standing at the end holding a non-majority element. For example, maybe they just happened to have not encountered anyone with a different value while everyone else sat down.

The reason for the second pass is to differentiate between these two cases. If there is a majority at all, it has to end up as the final candidate. If there isn’t, something might still end up as the final candidate and you need to rule that case out.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are confused about what majority element is. The candidate only qualifies if its frequency is more than half of the total list i.e.

```
if frequency(majority_element) > total_size_of_list / 2: return True
```

First pass only gets the possible candidate for Majority Voting. Second pass confirms if it is really majority element or not.

For example:-
In following list

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Possible candidate for majority element is 5.
But Frequency of 5 in the list is 3 only which is less than half of list size and thus it is not a majority element and thus the test fails but you won't even know it if you don't make the second pass.

I hope it helps!

Comment: See, In first pass you only get the possible candidate and not even frequency of the candidate which you could compare to the size/2. So we do need to confirm if we got the correct element or not and hence the second pass.

Answer (score 0):

I think a second pass is required when you have to compare your element with the upper limit if you only want to find the element which repeated more than n/2 than first pass will do the work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).